# Java regex capture not working

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression:

```
l:([0-9]+)
```

This should match this string and return three captures (according to [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com))

```
"l:32, l:98, l:234"
```

Here is my code:

```
Pattern p ...
Matcher m = p.matcher(...);
m.find();
System.out.println(m.groupCount());
```

This prints out 1 (group) when there are three, so I can only do `m.group(1)` which will only return 32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `Matcher.find` finds the *next* instance of the match, or returns false if there are no more.  Try calling it three times and see if you have all your expected groups.

To clarify, `m.group(1)` is trying to find the first group expression *in your regular expression*.  You only have one such group expression in your regex, so `group(2)` would never make sense.  You probably need to call `m.find()` in a loop until it returns false, grabbing the group result at each iteration.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I am simply doing `while (m.find()) ... m.group(1) ... ` like @Deco said

Answer (score 1):

I think it needs to be

```
Pattern p ...
Matcher m = p.matcher(...);
int count = 0;

while(m.find()) {
    count++;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

find looks for the next match, so using a while loop will find all matches.

Answer (score 1):

`Matcher.find()` returns false when there are no more matches, so you can do a `while loop` whilst getting and processing each `group`. For example, if you want to print all matches, you can use the following:

```
    Matcher m;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("l:([0-9]+)");
    m = p.matcher("l:32, l:98, l:1234");

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If input string format is fixed you could use following regex

```
"l:32, l:98, l:234".split("(, )?l:")
```

Output

```
[, 32, 98, 234]
```

Comment: That's a good approach, but this example that I gave is an extremely simplified version of what I'm actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: what you see(k) is what you get ;)