# Java regex doesn't find numbers

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to parse some text, but for some strange reason, Java regex doesn't work. For example, I've tried:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z][0-9]*,[0-9]*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("H3,4");
```

and it simply gives No match found exception, when I try to get the numbers m.group(1) and m.group(2). Am I missing something about how Java regex works?

Comment: See [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176559/java-regex-capture-not-working/8176617#8176617) for code examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

1. You must actually call `matches()` or `find()` on the matcher first.
2. Your regex must actually contain capturing groups

Example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z](\\d*),(\\d*)");
matcher m = p.matcher("H3,4");
if (m.matches()) {
    // use m.group(1), m.group(2) here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need the parenthesis to specify what is part of each group. I changed the leading part to be anything that's not a digit, 0 or more times. What's in each group is 1 or more digits. So, not * but + instead.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]*([0-9]+),([0-9]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("H3,4");
if (m.matches())
{
  String g1 = m.group(1);
  String g2 = m.group(2);
}
```